# VS Code TFS is showing wrong project

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-code

I have setup Team Foundation Server support in my VS Code. As the docs say I open the workspace folder and the extensions sees there is TFS support in this workspace but the project shown in the status bar is for another project on the TFS.

What is wrong here?

Comment: What's that mean for `another project`? another `Team Project` or another specific develop project?

Answer (score 0):

Generally it will display the Team Project name which is based on your workspace when you connect to TFS.

So, if you mean the wrong Team Project name, then you need to check your workspace first, make sure it's really mapped to the correct Team Project.

You can also try to create a new workspace and map to the specific Team Project, then check it again.

If you mean the wrong develop project with the specific solution, then you can switch to the correct project/solution by clicking the **switch** button at bottom-right corner.

[image]

Comment: @Jon Farmer Have you resolved the issue? any update?